# Swipe whole recyclerview from right to left not single item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I want to animate whole recyclerview from right to left and **not single item**. On animating i want to show textview from each row. i had tried implementing touch listener but not working. anyone has any idea ?[image]

Comment: please can you explain more, or using illustrations ?

Comment: on swipe left, the screen should slide left and timestamp should be visible i have attached image. I am able to get the swipe but not able to animate recyclerview